# XML File into SQL, duplicate tags, and filtering? How to

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

So I have an XML file as follows (last code block example)... you'll notice below, there are tags for "ITEM" with a name and a value tag nested.  Sometimes, there are 6 items per xml file, sometimes 2.  They are NOT always in the same order.  Initially, when I was querying the data I assumed from looking at the first 20 files that there would be always 6 Items... however, sometimes, there isn't.  How can I filter when the Name of the Item = "something specific"....

In this example below, file count

For example

```
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/JobSpecificInformation/Item/Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'
```

Sometimes, this is a file count, other times if a file count wasn't in the file, it is actually a database size....so my calculations and info in the columns is wrong.

Since there are a random set of tags with the same name, how can I filter so I know what I am dealing with?

Case didn't seem to be the way to go...I am using something like this but, obviously, sometimes the Values aren't actually what they are expected to be.. help!

```
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/WorkspaceAncestry/WorkspaceAncestry/WorkspaceName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS [WorkspaceName],
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/JobSpecificInformation/Item/Value)[0]', 'varchar(100)') AS [FileCount],
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/JobSpecificInformation/Item/Value)[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS [FileSize],
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/JobSpecificInformation/Item/Value)[3]', 'varchar(250)') AS [DatabaseSize],
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/JobSpecificInformation/Item/Value)[4]', 'varchar(100)') AS [DTIndexSize],
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/WorkspaceAncestry/WorkspaceAncestry/EventType)[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS [EventType],
CAST(Body AS XML).value('(/JobCompleteStatistics/WorkspaceAncestry/WorkspaceAncestry/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS [EventType2]
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<JobCompleteStatistics xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <JobType>Archive</JobType>
  <OriginalWorkspaceGuid>12964d66-3ee9-4072-8771-3cc339d1fe6d</OriginalWorkspaceGuid>
  <CurrentWorkspaceGuid>12964d66-3ee9-4072-8771-3cc339d1fe6d</CurrentWorkspaceGuid>
  <ARMVersion>9.6.1.14</ARMVersion>
  <ExecutionType>Manual</ExecutionType>
  <WorkspaceAncestry>
    <WorkspaceAncestry>
      <EventTime>2018-04-23T19:10:35Z</EventTime>
      <EventType>Archive</EventType>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <InstanceName>Instance1</InstanceName>
      <WorkspaceGuid>12964d66-3ee9-4072-8771-3cc339d1fe6d</WorkspaceGuid>
      <WorkspaceName>Workspace 1</WorkspaceName>
    </WorkspaceAncestry>
  </WorkspaceAncestry>
  <CompletionTime>2018-04-23T23:42:34Z</CompletionTime>
  <ElapsedTime>00:04:32:22</ElapsedTime>
  <ErrorCount>0</ErrorCount>
  <JobSpecificInformation>
    <Item>
      <Name>File Count</Name>
      <Value>1847139</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>File Size</Name>
      <Value>385894107665</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Database Size</Name>
      <Value>6930992</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>DtIndex Size</Name>
      <Value>5859343220</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Content Analytics Size</Name>
      <Value>0</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Archive Compression Level</Name>
      <Value>0</Value>
    </Item>
  </JobSpecificInformation>
  <RetryCount>0</RetryCount>
</JobCompleteStatistics>
```

Comment: Even though the Items may appear in random order is there a consistent set of Name values?

Comment: Yes, there will be one of a variety of different values.  This is for an export tool, for some software.  So, if I were to choose to NOT export a certain component, then the specific name/value set won't exist - but it will come from a pool of values.  6 is max, and they are all known

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot assume that all `Item` nodes will always be present and that they'll always be in a given order, but there is a known set of values that appears in `Name` nodes, then you can specify XPath filter expressions to assert the order you need, e.g.:

```sql
select
  JobSpecificInformation.value('(Item[Name/text()="Archive Compression Level"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [Archive Compression Level],
  JobSpecificInformation.value('(Item[Name/text()="Content Analytics Size"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [Content Analytics Size],
  JobSpecificInformation.value('(Item[Name/text()="Database Size"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [Database Size],
  JobSpecificInformation.value('(Item[Name/text()="DtIndex Size"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [DtIndex Size],
  JobSpecificInformation.value('(Item[Name/text()="File Count"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [File Count],
  JobSpecificInformation.value('(Item[Name/text()="File Size"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [File Size]
from dbo.Example
cross apply (select cast(Body as XML)) foo(BodyXML)
cross apply BodyXML.nodes('/JobCompleteStatistics/JobSpecificInformation') stats(JobSpecificInformation);
```

Which returns the results:

| Archive Compression Level | Content Analytics Size | Database Size | DtIndex Size | File Count | File Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 6930992 | 5859343220 | 1847139 | 385894107665 |

Comment: Perfect, I haven't tested yet but this appears to be what I was looking for! Appreciate it.